# How would I put 4 chars into a single int?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I am working on a replica GM buffer system in C++ to get familiar with bits and such, and it's not bad, but I've run into a problem. How do I push 4 different chars into an int? I am not the best at bitwise stuff, I've never used it. I've got no idea how to.

In the thing, I have an array of chars; of size `byteArraySize` and when I call the grab int function, it would take the bytes from `bufferPointer + 4` to `bufferPointer`; backwards to grab the int properly.

I read a **bit** on bitshifting (lol), and I thought I could like bitshift every char's bits `i` to the right. I've just got no clue where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `byte0 | (byte1 << 8) | (byte2 << 16) | (byte3 << 24)`?

Comment: I see no evidence of research effort here. This is really basic and simple. Did you try anything at all? Read a book? Take an introductory course on programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedantically, in pure standard C++14 or C++11, you probably cannot.

AFAIK, nothing forbids an hypothetical C++14 implementation to have all of `char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long` to be the same types (at least the same internal representation), and be all 64 bits, (or 96 bits, or 128 bits) and all of `sizeof` 1. The recent C and C++ standards mandate that `long long`  has at least 64 bits.

<sup>IIRC, some weird C implementation above some Common Lisp is doing similar things.</sup>

But of course, there is no such C++14 implementation in practice.

In practice, on most implementations, `char`-s are 8 bits bytes (perhaps `signed` perhaps `unsigned`) and `int`-s are often 32 bits words (e.g. are `std::int32_t`), and you obviously could code

```
 inline int pack4chars(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4) {
    return ((int)(((unsigned char)c1) << 24)
            |  (int)(((unsigned char)c2) << 16)
            |  (int)(((unsigned char)c3) << 8)
            |  (int)((unsigned char)c4));
}
```

<sup>The cast to `(unsigned char)` is needed because some implementations have signed `char`-s and others have unsigned ones.</sup>

Read also about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), [htonl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htonl.3.html)

Comment: Thanks, your code is the easiest to understand that I've seen!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pack 4 `char`s (actually `sizeof(int)` `char`s) into an `int`. Here's how you could do it:

```
unsigned int packChars(unsigned char *c)
{
  unsigned int val = u0;
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(unsigned int); ++idx) {
    val |= c[idx] << (idx * CHAR_BIT);
  }
}
```

I'm using unsigned types, because bit shifting gets tricky when sign bits are involved. Also not that the code above is intentionally generic in the sizes used: `sizeof(unsigned int)` gives you the number of `char` units which fit into `unsigned int`, and `CHAR_BIT` specifies the number of bits in a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a union which have all its members aligned from the same offset in memory.

Example:

```
union Color
{
    std::uint32_t m_rgba;

    struct
    {
        std::uint8_t m_a;
        std::uint8_t m_b;
        std::uint8_t m_g;
        std::uint8_t m_r;
    };
};

Color white = { 0xffffffff };
```

Comment: I don't think that this is quite what you meant.... a nested struct, perhaps?

Comment: you are absolutely right

Comment: It commonly works but unfortunately it is explicitely undefined behaviour according to the standard: *In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at
most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time*

Comment: this doesn't mean that it is "explicitely undefined bahaviour". Following the quoted statement, the standard also mentions: "The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest
of its non-static data members. Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a
struct. All non-static data members of a union object have the same address". When accessing a member of the union, you are in fact accessing the same area in memory as any other member of the same union.

Comment: @KnightsWatch: you are right it is not explicit, but as it explicitely says *In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static
data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence
of T1 and T2*, I assume that reading a data member not respecting that was not allowed.

Comment: Linguistically speaking, if the standard doesn't define what happens if you do something, like flip back and forth between active union members, you have undefined behaviour. If it's not defined, it's undefined.

Comment: You are right. What is defined in the spec: "The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types is the longest sequence of nonstatic
data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the
structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types and either neither entity is a bit-field
or both are bit-fields with the same width". What is not defined is the spec: the endianness of the data in memory which is architechture specific.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be aware, that sizeof(int) does not have to be 4 *sizeof(char). Standard only guarantees, that sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char) and nothing more.

In fact int can be the same size with char's size (or bigger), But you never know, unless you find this out.